# Mockito throwing a NullpointerException on using a mock

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm trying to create test cases for a webservice but I'm getting nullpointerexception. This is the web service:

```
@Path("friendservice")
public class FriendWebService {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FriendWebService.class);

@EJB
private FriendRequestServiceInterface friendRequestService;

@GET
@Path("friendrequest")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String createFriendRequest(
        @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    logger.info("createFriendRequest called");

    String result = "false";
    User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
    User otherUser = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("profileuser");
    if ((user != null) && (otherUser != null)) {
        logger.info("Got two users from session, creating friend request.");
        if (friendRequestService.createFriendRequest(user, otherUser)) {
            result = "true";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

This is my test class:

```
public class FriendWebServiceTest {
@Mock
FriendRequestServiceInterface FriendRequestService;
@Mock
Logger mockedLogger = mock(Logger.class);
@Mock
HttpServletRequest mockedRequest = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
@Mock
HttpSession mockedSession = mock(HttpSession.class);
@Mock
User mockedUser = mock(User.class);
@Mock
User mockedOtherUser = mock(User.class);
@InjectMocks
FriendWebService friendWebService = new FriendWebService();

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

}

@Test
public void testCreateFriendRequest() throws Exception {
    when(mockedRequest.getSession()).thenReturn(mockedSession);
    when(mockedSession.getAttribute("user")).thenReturn(mockedUser);
    when(mockedSession.getAttribute("profileuser")).thenReturn(mockedOtherUser);
    when(FriendRequestService.createFriendRequest(mockedUser, mockedOtherUser)).thenReturn(true);
    assertTrue(friendWebService.createFriendRequest(mockedRequest) == "true");
}
```

The NullPointerException occurs at "when(FriendRequestService.createFriendRequest(mockedUser, mockedOtherUser)).thenReturn(true);"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are chaining method calls on your mocked instance:

```
@Mock
HttpServletRequest mockedRequest = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
```

First of all, you do not need to do both, either use the `@Mock` annotation or the `mock` method. Like this, you first assign a Mock and then replace this instance with another mock. I recommend the annotation as it adds some context to the mock such as the field's name. This might already cause your `NullPointerException` as you however never activate the annotations by calling:

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

as you do not consequently mock all instances with both measures so far. However, even doing so will further result in your exception, so let's move ahead.

Within `friendWebService.createFriendRequest(mockedRequest)` you call:

```
User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
User otherUser = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("profileuser");
```

where you call a method on two mocks for which you did not specify any behavior. These mocks do by default return `null`. You need to specify behavior for this such as:

```
when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(myMockedSession);
```

before performing this chained call. Based on this, you can then specify how to react to calls on this mocked instance such as returning your user mocks.

Comment: I've tried using only Mock annotations but that produces an error on "when(mockedRequest.getSession()).thenReturn(mockedSession);" but this problem disappears when you use mock() method. I use mock method and remove the annotations but i want to know why annotations fail.

Comment: Did you call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` at some point?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling `initMocks`, You probably need to annotate with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` to your `FriendWebServiceTest` class.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try adding `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` or `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` annotations to your `FriendWebServiceTest` class for JUnit4 and JUnit5 respectively.